# Why there is no "of" in "Immigration, Refugees and Citizenship Canada"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

My inner implicit grammar compass tells me that there's an "of" missing in  "Immigration, Refugees and Citizenship Canada" and it should be "Immigration, Refugees and Citizenship **Of** Canada", but I think that the possibility that a government of an English speaking country being wrong is far less than me, as someone who never lived in an English speaking country and never had a formal learning experience of Englis, being right.
So, What am I missing here?

[You can see the name ("Immigration, Refugees and Citizenship Canada") here.](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship.html)

Comment: I'm not from Canada but I've noticed that: Revenue Canada, Statistics Canada, Health Canada. It just struck me as a bit of distinctive branding. I'd be interested in the background too. Edit: I just discovered that what was Revenue Canada has been rolled into the Canada Revenue Agency.

Comment: @GreenGrassoHolm Interesting points. It's been bugging me too for some time now. So maybe this is not one of those "but this one is an exception" kind of things, but just a "distinctive branding"?  Let's see what others have to say.

Comment: 'Team GB', 'Air France', the TV show 'Railroad Alaska' etc show this punchy form of postmodification. I think only one of these names is older than I am.

Comment: Also: Team Canada?

Comment: It is worth noting that it is not only *of* that is absent here, but also *Department*, *Service*, or any similar term.

Comment: Whatever the appropriate formal answer to this is, I just want to confirm for you that it does sound like it is missing things. Note that if it were just 'Immigration', the preposition should be 'to', also missing.

Answer (score 1):

Canadian institutions sometimes have English names that parallel French equivalents

> Immigration, Refugees and Citizenship  Canada

parallels

> [Immigration, Réfugiés et Citoyenneté Canada](https://www.canada.ca/fr/immigration-refugies-citoyennete.html)

Canada Post doesn't seem the best English name for the Canadian mail system, but it does parallel the French  [Postes Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada_Post), although the words are inverted.

In Canada  both English and French are  official in the entire country. Frequently no parallels with English and French are possible in names of institutions,  but when they are , it probably helps national unity that names are similar in the two languages.

Comment: This is all true, but it is not clear how it answers the OP’s question, which was specifically about the absence of the preposition *of*. Writing ‘du Canada’ is as easy as writing ‘of Canada’.

Comment: I completely agree about the prepositions... except that by omitting them the Canadian Government helps establish unusual names for institutions which helps, perhaps, the parallel forms when possible.  "Canada" is the most parallel form and rarely is seen as "Canadian" or Canadien" . There is some tradition here. The first CBC logo had "Radio Canada"  (1940) on it and currently it is "Radio-Canada" in French uses. What seems lacking in correct grammar also seems as a way to prevent English from becoming overbearing.

Comment: Boxcars belonging to the Canadian National railroad have (or had) "Canadian National" one one side and "Canadien National" on the other.

Comment: Well, there's also Radio Australia. Was that named coined under the influence of French? What about  Radio Deutsche Welle? Radio Moscow (when it existed), etc etc